# GBQ SQL: How to find first instance of X value and pull a corresponding row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that records the history of each ID per LOCATION. This table is updated each day to keep track of the history of any change in a certain row(ID). Note: The date field is not in chronological order.

```
ID   Count   Date (datetime type)
1    20      2020-01-15T12:00:00.000
1    16      2020-03-15T12:00:00.000
1    13      2020-04-15T12:00:00.000
1    4       2020-05-15T12:00:00.000
1    0       2020-06-15T12:00:00.000
2    20      2020-01-15T12:00:00.000
2    10      2020-02-15T12:00:00.000
3    12      2020-01-15T12:00:00.000
3    10      2020-02-15T12:00:00.000
3    0       2020-03-15T12:00:00.000
```

For each unique ID, I need to pull the first instance (oldest date) when the Count value is zero. If a unique ID does not have an instance where it Count value is zero, I need to pull the most current Count value.

Here's what my results should look like below:

```
ID   Count   Date (datetime type)
1    0       2020-06-15T12:00:00.000
2    10      2020-02-15T12:00:00.000
3    0       2020-03-15T12:00:00.000
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to code this in Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE
  CASE COUNTIF(count = 0) 
    WHEN 0 THEN ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
    ELSE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY count, date LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
  END 
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY id
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

```
Row id  count   date     
1   1   0       2020-05-15 12:00:00 UTC  
2   2   10      2020-03-15 12:00:00 UTC  
3   3   0       2020-06-15 12:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: What is the SELECT AS VALUE doing?

Comment: remove it and run without it and you will see the difference :o) hope it will be self-explanatory. but in short it is kind of opposite to `AS STRUCT` and allows to output struct's fields only. You can run `select AS VALUE struct(1 as x, 2 as y)` and `select  struct(1 as x, 2 as y)` to see difference

Comment: I forgot one crucial thing about this table. Each unique ID has a specific location tied to it. So I would need to account for the Unique ID + location combo and apply the logic to filter out...I updated the table to show you how the results should look like

Comment: this sounds like a new question. in such cases - you should post the new question with relevant details. Note: on SO it is not considered best practice to update/change core of question after at least one answer is provided as it invalidates that answer and efforts that we apply in trying to help you!

Comment: So, having above in mind  - my recommendation 1) revert your question back to original 2) accept and vote up the answer(s) if any helped 3) post new question in new post - Thank you for considering :o)

Comment: btw. fix is extremely simple - but i will not update my already given answer to original question - but will happily do  so in the new posted question!

Comment: Hi, sorry, I will update back to orignal question. I am new to SO, so please forgive me. I will post a new question! Thanks!

Comment: Sure. no problem. thank you for listening :o) Also consider voting up the answers that worked/helped and accept the one that helped best for you. This is important "procedure" here on SO

Comment: Also note: You can use check sign to the left of the answer to accept it!

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want the last row for each `id`?

One method is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by case when count = 0 then date end nulls last,
                                         date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

But I also like using aggregation in BigQuery:

```
select (array_agg(t order by date desc limit 1))[ordinal(1)]
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, it's not necessarily the last row (but it could be). If an ID has a zero in the Count field, I want the oldest dated row that has the zero in the Count field. However, if the ID does not have a zero in the Count field, I want the most current dated row info. Does that make sense? I tried to show what my results table should look like.

Comment: @SJK Just change the order by clause to `order by counts asc, date desc`

Comment: @SJK . . . I fixed the logic.  It is a little tricky because sometimes you want the earliest date and sometimes the latest date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I forgot one crucial thing about this table. Each unique ID has a specific location tied to it. So I would need to account for the Unique ID + location combo and apply the logic to filter out...I updated the table to show you how the results should look like.